# SignalR with Identity framework

Tags: entity-framework, signalr, asp.net-identity

Honestly, I have searched a lot but I can't get a simple tutorial on SignalR working with Identity framework.

I have made my Identity User model and everything else related to it.

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{

    // Foreign keys and relations
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual List<UserLanguageLevel> Languages { get; set; }
    public virtual List<UserMeta> Meta { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ChatRoom> ChatRooms { get; set; }
    public User()
    {
        this.Meta = new List<UserMeta>();
        this.Languages = new List<UserLanguageLevel>();
        this.ChatRooms = new List<ChatRoom>();
    }


}
```

I just want to access the claims in the OnConnected() method of SignalR Hub but I don't know how to.

Please provide related good information and topics about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about accessing the Context's properties?

```
 System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext = Context.Request.GetHttpContext();
 System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal user = Context.User;
```

This will allow you to access the user and the claims. I got this code from the [official docs](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server).

That being said, I'm not so sure if it's a great idea to directly access these properties to get to the current user. You could use the ConnectionId and map that to a user, as is explained [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections).